# В string.xml в одной строке сделать ссылку на другую

Tags: android, java

Хочется сделать из одной строки ссылку на другую, при этом чтобы они обе были в string.xml, сделал что эдакое

```
<string name="hello">Hello</string>
<string name="world">World</string>

<string-array name="aloha">
   <item>@string/hello</item>
   <item>@string/world</item>
</string-array>
```

Как правильно вызвать string-array? Если по сути на обработчике спрашивает @string/aloha, поскольку все остальные значения для обработки являются простыми строками,
то есть в объекте нужно установить свойство obj(String alo) через (R.string.aloha)

Хотелось бы что-то вроде toString(R.array.aloha)

пришлось сделать не совсем так, как хотелось.

```
public String Welcome ;
public String getString()
{
    String str = "" ;
    String[] bld = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.aloha);

    for (int i = 0; i < bld.length; i++)
    {
        str = str.concat( bld[i]) ;
    }
    Welcome = str;
    return str;

}
```

Welcome затем может снова использоваться без вызова, просто так...

это работает, но это не то, потому что базовый класс на самом деле public Static obj(String alo) и в нём нельзя использовать getResources() и сейчас приходится в конечный textView вставлять Welcome, а не свойство obj.alo

это для реализации changelog, чтобы не писать текст одним куском, а добавлять новые строки.итемы с переводом и без последующих изменений.